# MassTransit Producer takes 60 seconds to Consume an event

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I have 2 projects:

1. A MassTransit (Topshelf Windows Service) called `Service.Endpoints`
2. A Console App client trying to communicate with it called `TestConsole`.

The overall requirement is as follows:

1. `TestConsole` sends `SolveProblemCommand`
2. `Service.Endpoints` Consumes the command and Publishes `ProblemSolvedEvent`
3. `TestConsole` Consumes the event.

### The problem:

All the above steps work fine except that step 3 (`TestConsole` consuming the event) only happens around 60 seconds after the event is published. The following error is displayed first (after 60 seconds) and then the Consumer received the call.

```
Timeout waiting for consumer to exit: rabbitmq://localhost:5672/bus-PC-NAME-TestConsole.vshost-4sboyydjz6ne6mz6bdky1b7ad4?durable=false&autodelete=true&prefetch=16
```

Timeout waiting for consumer to exit: rabbitmq://localhost:5672/problemsolved.queue?prefetch=16

### The code:

#### Service.Endpoints.csproj

```
bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus(new AppSettings(), (cfg, host) =>
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.SolveProblemQueue, e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<SolveProblemCommandConsumer>(NinjectConfig.CurrentKernel);
    });
});

bus.Start();

class SolveProblemCommandConsumer : IConsumer<SolveProblemCommand>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SolveProblemCommand> context)
    {
        var controller = new Controller(context.Message.Problem);
        var results = await controller.Start(context.Message.Options);
        await context.Publish(new ProblemSolvedEvent(results));
    }
}
```

#### TestConsole.csproj

```
var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus(new AppSettings(), (cfg, host) =>
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.ProblemSolvedQueue, e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<ProblemSolvedEventConsumer>();
    });
});

var sendToUri = new Uri($"{RabbitMqConstants.RabbitMqUri}{RabbitMqConstants.SolveProblemQueue}");
var endpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(sendToUri);
bus.Start();

await endpoint.Send(someMessage);


class ProblemSolvedEventConsumer : IConsumer<ProblemSolvedEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ProblemSolvedEvent> context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it sounds like 60 seconds is a timeout that you hit from console when sending first message (command), are you sure you are not synchronously blocking console? you did not share any listening code yet..

Comment: The thing that helped me diagnose these problems the most was installing the web plugin for RabbitMQ.  It will allow you to look at exchanges and queues to see if your message actually was sent.  If you see it sitting in a queue then you know your consumer is incorrect.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I think I've shared all the code. Two `cfg.ReceiveEndpoint()` calls, two `Consumer<T>()` calls and two `IConsumer<T>` classes. What listening code is missing?

Comment: @phil Thanks for the tip, I have the management plugin installed and can see the message sitting in the queue for 60 seconds and then it suddenly is correctly consumed by the expected consumer. The problem is just the 60 delay. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Next question is how big is the message.  I had something like that happen when I attempted to pass a large file in the message.

Comment: @Phil Now you might be on to something. It's pretty big. About 2MB.

Comment: If you need to test your performance of MT with RabbitMQ, you can use the benchmarking tool. What you're seeing is not typical: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Benchmark

Comment: Also, if you're doing request, response, use the RequestClient, that cleans up a lot of the bus logic. And if you don't need durable requests, turn off durability and save yourself a bunch of disk writes.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, I do need a response back to the client, but don't want to do a blocking call (seems a bit wrong). That's why I am trying to use two separate queues, one for the request and one for the response. I don't think it is anything to do with performance, because I can debug it and the breakpoints all get hit in a timely manner. It definitely seems more like there is some unclosed resource that is stopping other messages from being picked up from the queue.

Comment: So the timeout is actually waiting for your consumer to exit. Are you sure it's completing and returning from the `Consume` method? I'm guessing that it isn't...

Comment: Yes. The consumer executes the last line in the consume method successfully, gets a result and then raises the event with the result as one of the properties (`await context.Publish(new ProblemSolvedEvent(results));`). Even that event is consumed successfully with the correct result data, but only 60 seconds later.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Found the issue - I was using one `IBusControl` for sending and listening, as can be seen in the example code `TestConsole.csproj`. As soon as I created two separate bus objects it worked fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `TestConsole.csproj` project I reuse the same `IBusControl` object to send the command and to consume the event. Once I created two separate bus objects it worked as expected.